# Combining Certs Together? Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: certificates, wpa2

Is there anyway I can combine certificates together?

I went to my Universities IT Help Desk about not being able to connect to their WPA2 Enterprise Wifi and they handed me 4 Certs Intermediate 1.crt, Intermediate 2.crt, Root.crt, ServerCertifacate.crt. I tried these and with none of them working I went back to the IT Help Desk and they said that they contacted someone about the issue and they said to combine the certs however they had no idea how to do that and or which certs to combine.

So now I come to the wonderful community of AskUbuntu (:

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily combine text (assuming your certificates are text files) by copying and paste the content with any text editor. You can also combine the text by the current command:

```
cat Intermediate\ 1.crt Intermediate\ 2.crt Root.crt Servercertifacate.crt > combined-certificates.pem
```

Comment: Thnks! I actually ended up doing >cat Root.crt "Intermediate1.crt" "Intermediate2.crt" cert_chain.crt  Thanks Though!!